# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-sTRicb-build/

Tags: django

I am trying to install Django and I get the following error, please 
let me know what seems to be the issue.

Thanks,

```
(ENV) AP-MacBook-Pro:bin $ sudo -H pip install django/
Processing ./django
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-sTRicb-build/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 60, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-sTRicb-build/
```

Answer (score 0):

**lru_cache** is only available in Python 3.

**Note**: the question shows python 2 is used on installation step. this exception "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'" shows it. You must use python 3 with django 2.0 because django 2.0 supports only python 3.

Comment: seems like the author of the question uses python 2 on installation step. this exception "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'" shows it. the author must use python 3 with django 2.0 because django 2.0 supports only python 3.